# Maintain equal column height when scaling window size up or down

Tags: css

I have 2 columns inside a container div both with a `width of 50%`, 1 column has dummy text etc the other has a google map iframe. I have wrapped a fluid container around the map and applied `position absolute;` to the iframe to expand the map inside its container but I notice the map seems to shrink and expand a lot beyond the contact column, can anyone advise how I can consistently make the map be the same height as the other column? I need this layout to remain fluid so the full 100% width

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xm6GW/1/

CSS

```
.col-ctn {
    width: 100%;
}
.col {
    width: 50%;
    background: silver
}
.contact-col {
    float: left;
}
.map-col {
    float: right;
}
.fluid-map {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    height: 0;
}
.fluid-map iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xm6GW/8/)**

### (Relevant) CSS

```
html,body,.col-ctn,.contact-col
{
    height: 100%;
}
.fluid-map {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done the changes as per your requirement but you have to change the css naming as per your requiremnet.

CSS:-

```
body, html {
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin:0;
}
.main_container
{
    width:100%;
    height:98%;
}
.info_container
{
    width:49.2%;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid;
    float:left;
}
.map_container
{
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid;
    float:right;
}
```

Html:-

```
<div class="main_container">
             <div class="info_container">
                 <div class="inner">
                     <h2>Header</h2>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
             </div>
                 <div class="map_container">
                     <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.co.uk/?ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=47.754098,12.480469&amp;spn=20.702603,37.353516&amp;z=4&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
                 </div>
        </div>
```

fiddle link:-
http://jsfiddle.net/Xm6GW/1/